# How to clone repo using deploy key?

Tags: git, github, deploy-keys

I successfully created a deploy key for a private repository using the method outlined [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys).

Now when I run `git clone repo_url` I would expect it to clone? But it doesn't. A pop up appears expecting git credentials (standard email/password<sup>1</sup>). Where have I gone wrong? I can `cat my_rsa_key` and see that it has been created successfully (saved to the default location).

Perhaps I have missed something or do I have to clone the repo using a different command?

<sup>1</sup> Which defeats the purpose of having the deploy key in the first place

#### Note

I am on windows server 2019

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`? If you don't want to share the URL, how is it composed (does it start with `http://`, `git@`, or something else)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably trying to clone the repo using `https` rather than `ssh`. When you click on "Clone or download" on github, you can choose `ssh`, which is the only way your deploy key will be used.